# How to update a WinJS UWP app after the Windows system accent color changes

Tags: uwp, winjs

I have 2 variables, `accentColor`, and `backgroundColor`. `backgroundColor` updates as expected when I change the Windows settings from Light to Dark mode, but `accentColor` does not change when I choose a new Windows accent color.

```
var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings(),
   accentColor = uiSettings.getColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.accent),
   backgroundColor = uiSettings.getColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.background);
```

Therefore I cannot update the UI to reflect the user's choice. Is this a bug? Is there a work around?

I am checking them on the visibilitychanged event.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged);
```

This occurs on Windows 10 Pro 1709 build 16299.309 but surprisingly works properly on Windows 10 Mobile!

Comment: You could detect the accent color changed in the [`colorvalueschanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.colorvalueschanged)event handler of `UISettings` instance.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT This got me pointed in the right direction. I also had an issue detecting the event because uiSettings was in the wrong scope or something (inside of an anonymous function), whereas visibiltychange is attached to document, so was working. Still not sure why backgroundColor updated, but not accentColor but it all works now! I can post the whole setup if anyone is interested in the complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect the accent color changed in the [`colorvalueschangedevent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.colorvalueschanged) handler of UISettings instance. When you change the system' theme accent color and it will be fired.

```
var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
uiSettings.addEventListener("colorvalueschanged", onColorChanged);

function onColorChanged() {

    var accentColor = uiSettings.getColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.accent);

}
```